# Google maps show street numbers

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

Is there any way to show more details on google maps v2 ? And by that I am referring to data displayed on map such as street & building number. Currently google does this only for Australia as can be seen [here](https://www.google.ro/maps/@-33.868231,151.2084959,18.41z) . I need to display this data for all the countries in the european union, thank you.